# Is there a way in Powershell for a boolean parameter to automatically be true if not specified when the function is called?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

If the function is called `myFunc -IsLightOn $true`, it should return nothing. `myFunc - IsLightOn $False` should return "Light off". However, not specifying true or false for `IsLightOn` parameter should default the variable to true and thus return nothing

```
function myFunc{
   Param(
    [bool]$IsLightOn
   ) if ($LightIsOn -EQ $false){
      Write-Host "Light off"
   }
}
```

Everything works when the value is specified but I don't know how to default `IsLightOn` to true.

Comment: Instead of a boolean parameter, you probably want to use a [switch parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#switch-parameters) instead; they're (usually) more intuitive. Ideally you want to arrange it so that `$false` is an appropriate default, so you'd name the switch `-LightOn` in this case (or somesuch).

Answer (score 3):

As the others have stated, the Switch parameter type is probably what you want. Typically, though, the switch is used to specify non-default behavior (so the default value is $false if the switch parameter is not provided). So you could do something similar to what TheIncorrigible1 said:

```
function Set-LightStatus {
    param(
        [switch] $Off
     )

    if ($Off) {
        'Light off'
    }  
}
```

If you want exactly what you asked for in the question, though, you can continue to use a Boolean parameter value. You can set defaults in the Param() block, like so:

```
function myFunc {
  param(
    [bool]$IsLightOn = $true
)
  if ($IsLightOn -EQ $false){ Write-Host "Light off" }  
}
```

Comment: So having the value specified in the Param() block wouldn't overwrite what the user inputs?

Comment: Nope, it's just specifying a default value for when no value is supplied by the user.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `[switch]` type:

```
function Set-LightStatus {
    param(
        [switch] $On
    )

    if (-not $On.IsPresent) {
        'Light off'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use default value in param like :

```
function myFunc{
    Param(
        [bool]$IsLightOn=$true # Default value
    ) 

    if (!$IsLightOn) { # CHECKING THE VALUE
        Write-Host "Light off" # PRINTING ON THE HOST
    } # END OF IF

} # END OF FUNCTION

myFunc # WITHOUT PASSING VALUE
myFunc -IsLightOn:$true # PASSING TRUE VALUE
myFunc -IsLightOn:$false # PASSING FALSE VALUE
```